# Django Simple Captcha Can't change Validation Error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, captcha

I want change validation error for Captcha input after the wrong value is entered, default value error is 'Invalid CAPTCHA' how can I change it ?

```py
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "id": "input-email"})
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "id": "input-password"})
    )

    captcha = CaptchaField(required=False, label='')
```

[Error text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FjIB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `error_messages` in the initialization:

```
captcha = CaptchaField(
    required=False, label='', error_messages={'invalid': '<Your custom message>'}
)
```

Just add the translations like [gettext_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) on the custom message if you need to.